# Using MSGraph API to get OneDrive Business file info including the latest version id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I'm calling the [get item API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) to get a file's info. In addition I would like to get its latest version's id. I can do that by issuing two requests:

`GET /me/drive/items/{item id}` - for getting the file's metadata.

`GET /me/drive/items/{item id}/versions?$top=1&$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime DESC` - to get the latest version's id.

I would rather get the same data using a single request. Using the following request:

`GET /me/drive/items/{item id}?$expand=versions($select=id)`

I am able to get a file's info including **all** of its versions' ids.

However, I haven't found a way to filter only the latest version. Specifying `$expand=versions($top=1;$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime DESC)` doesn't do anything (although the request does succeed). It seems that $expand will only support the $select parameter as specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter.

I'm concerned that for a file with a lot of versions, the expanded collection will get truncated, and that it might not include all of the versions - specifically the latest version. I couldn't find any specifications in the docs about the order of the expanded collection and the possibility of truncation.

Can this method be reliably used to get the latest version id in a single request? Is the any other possibility to get the data in a single request?

Thanks!